# Google web app script keeps asking for users to sign in?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, authorization

I have created my script and it works great.  I have changed the sharing so anybody can view it, but it still asks users to login to their Google account to run the script.

Here is the link:  [My script](https://script.google.com/d/1LS4bJ78_TAbwY-k44EwqaH32KuTTjUMUN4w4rugCiTl5S6guq8A7aZ0L/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you're web app is set to execute as `User accessing the web app`. This means they need to sign into a Google account to execute any of the code in your app.

You need to change this setting to: Execute the app as: `Me`
As well as change `Who has access to the app` from `Anyone` to `Anyone even anonymous`

Example:

[image]

The setting can be found by clicking on the cloud icon in the Apps Script IDE's toolbar. [image]

Edit: Added new image to reflect proper settings.

Comment: this is not complete. it needs to be "anyone even anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

It might be that they've updated the settings to where the least restrictive option is "Anyone" which would still require a log in. This is happening with my Google Workspace for Education account.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too, when I requested to any route except `/`, it will request me to login. I'm using general google account